# getting breakpoint retrieving addressbook data

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, abaddressbook

I am retrieving `phoneNumbers` and I am getting a breakpoint. I've spent the past few hours trying to fix it, but still no luck.

```
-(void)textMessage{
ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreate();
NSMutableArray *array =[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
NSMutableArray *temp;
NSMutableArray *temp2 = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
for(int i =0;i<[savedPeople count];i++){

    NSString *temp = (NSString*) ABAddressBookCopyPeopleWithName(addressBook, (CFStringRef)[savedPeople objectAtIndex:i]);
    NSLog(@"%@",temp);
    [temp2 addObject:temp];
    ABRecordRef thisPerson = (ABRecordRef)[temp2 objectAtIndex:i];
    ABMultiValueRef phoneProperty = ABRecordCopyValue(thisPerson, kABPersonPhoneProperty);
    NSLog(@"%@",phoneProperty);
}


array = temp2;
NSLog(@"%@",array);
CFRelease(addressBook);
}
```

![1] http://min.us/mQOzL3w5V

Anybody know what's wrong with it?

Comment: possible duplicate of ["Thread 1: stopped at breakpoint" error when initializing an NSURL object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10016890/thread-1-stopped-at-breakpoint-error-when-initializing-an-nsurl-object)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Breakpoints are somthing that you set, not errors. Go to the breakpoint inspector:
[image]

And delete any entries you find there. You can also turn off breakpoints temporarily with the Breakpoints button:

[image]

or via the menu command Product>Debug>Deactivate Breakpoints.

Comment: it still does not run/continue after i deactivate breakpoint, is this line wrong? ABMultiValueRef phoneProperty = ABRecordCopyValue(thisPerson, kABPersonPhoneProperty);

Comment: Does it crash? What does the console say?

Comment: Well, that might be why you set a breakpoint in the first place. That's a completely different question, though. You'll need to do some debugging yourself and provide the stack trace when you ask about it.