# Can't add object to NSMutableDictionary (iOS, Objective-C)

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsmutabledictionary

I am trying to add an object to an `NSMutableDictionary` using the `setObject:forKey:` function,
but for whatever reason, when I run my app in the iPhone simulator and try to perform the action, the code stops at the line were I am trying to add the object to the dictionary. The line where the program gets stuck is as follows:

```
[_dict setObject:_tf.text forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"keywords_%i", [_keywordsArray count]]];
```

Where '_dict' is an `NSMutableDictionary` object, '_tf' is a `UITextField`, and '_keywordsArray' is an `NSMutableArray`.

Overall, I am using the objects (aka keys) from my dictionary to populate an `NSMutableArray`, which is used to fill a `UIPickerView`. Initially, I load the dictionary from a .plist file, and I can tell the `NSMutableDictionary` and the `NSMutableArray` are both getting populated/filled correctly, and that the `UIPickerView` is working fine, the only part that isn't working is adding objects to the `NSMutableDictionary` (when the user presses a button in the UI). Also, I did get an error once that said that the `NSMutableArray` had a count of 0 (zero), when clearly it didn't.

Any help/suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What error message are you getting?

Comment: It would also be good to have a debug `watch`, where we can really see that what you claim to be NSMutableArray is one and its not NSArray. It recently happened to me that I had accepted an NSArray returned by sortArrayWithSelector... in a variable defined as NSMutableArray. It did not give problems in that part of the code, but when I tried to removeObject from this array, the app crashed. And I found out that its the sort function which is returning an NSArray. The error only shows up later.

Comment: Use the debugger and breakpoints to step by step the code. It might be  that you are pointing to the incorrect object, the NSMutableArray has a weak retain tag OR that you didn't alloc init something

Comment: The error I'm getting is 'Thread 1: breakpoint 1.1'.

Also, @OzairKafray: I checked for what you suggested, and I don't believe that's the error. I can post all of the code if that helps at all.

Comment: possible duplicate of [getting breakpoint retrieving addressbook data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10406572/getting-breakpoint-retrieving-addressbook-data)

Comment: Breakpoints aren't errors. They're something you control.