# iOS7 Storyboards: App crashes after calling addSubview

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios7, storyboard, xib

I am working with the iOS book ["Hello iOS Development"](http://manning.com/franco/). I coded along the book and just finished chapter 4. After implementing everything like in the book my app crashes.

I guess it's because I used Storyboards (Xcode 5 and iOS7), the author uses XIB files. Here's an image of the error:

[image]

What does the error mean? What's wrong with it? Does the addSubview refer to the XIB files I don't use due to Storyboards?

I'd really appreciate your help with this!

Comment: possible duplicate of ["Thread 1: stopped at breakpoint" error when initializing an NSURL object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10016890/thread-1-stopped-at-breakpoint-error-when-initializing-an-nsurl-object)

Comment: What is the exact crash?

Comment: @LeoNatan: It's not a crash. The highlight says "breakpoint".

Comment: @JoshCaswell Did you read the question? "After implementing everything like in the book my app crashes." I am assuming the screenshot is after enabling breakpoint on exceptions. That is why I think your close proposal is incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot simply `alloc] init` a view controller whose view is defined in a storyboard or XIB file, as you have. Doing so will not yield what you expect.

If you are using a storyboard, you should give your card view controller an identifier in the storyboard, and then `[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"_CardViewControllerIdentifier"];`
This will create a view controller with a view as set in the storyboard.

If you do not use a storyboard, but a xib file, you should use `initWithNibName:bundle:` to instantiate your view controller.