# NSBundle.mainBundle().bundleIdentifier! + ".\(self.rawValue)" in swift 3.0?

Tags: ios, swift

How can I write the code:

```
NSBundle.mainBundle().bundleIdentifier! + ".\(self.rawValue)"
```

in Swift 3.0?
Edit: Never mind,I figured it.

Comment: NSBundle is renamed to Bundle in Swift 3, and *documented* here: https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/bundle. – Also your question makes (sorry!) no sense without knowing what `self` is.

Comment: @MartinR I wrote return Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier! + ".\(self.rawValue)" (as part of doing 3d touch) and it says Thread 1: breakpoint 1.1

Comment: [Thread 1 stopped at breakpoint error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10016890/thread-1-stopped-at-breakpoint-error-when-initializing-an-nsurl-object/10016939#10016939)

Comment: I did the same to the second shortcut Item. and when I'm trying to open it, it's crashing. and it's wrote Thread 1: signal SIGABRT. what do I need to do? P.S I wrote self.window?.rootViewController?.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil) in the applicationDidEnterBackground(). does it have something to do with it?

Comment: @MartinR I know, I'm sorry I'm new in swift.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier! + ".\(self.rawValue)"
```

`NS` prefix is omitted in swift 3

Working code examples:-

```
let rawValue = "Testing stackoverflow"
let stringValue1 = Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier! + "test"
let stringValue2 = Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier! + "\(rawValue)"
```

[image]

Comment: it doesn't work. it asks to change mainBundle to main

Comment: I have update [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39837772/988169). Please check the working code example.