# Application is terminated due error on dequeuing cells

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, crash

I'm a newbie in XCode and iOS development and trying to create a simple app to display a players data in table view. I can build project without any warnings or errors, but when I'm running the application the app execution stops at this place. Could someone help and explain what I'm doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: The cutest question on SO :)

Comment: I'm not sure if the other question really counts as a duplicate. I mean there is almost no way to find that question when searching. Unless you know what exactly to search for. Perhaps the wording of that question should be changed.

Comment: @Honey It has nothing to do with the wording of the question. The answer to that question is the answer to this question. That is all the OP needs to know.

Comment: @Honey and if you don't like that one there's this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10016890/thread-1-stopped-at-breakpoint-error-when-initializing-an-nsurl-object The point is that this has been asked and answered many times before.

Comment: @matt I don't think that's the correct logic. I mean to close a question, because *somehow* you can find your answer in another answer. If that is the case then a tremendous amount of questions should be marked as duplicate. Many answers that include link to other answers fall into that category.

Comment: "If that is the case then a tremendous amount of questions should be marked as duplicate" _Exactly so_. That is why I spend so much time hammering duplicates. The amount of bandwidth wastage on Stack Overflow is terrible. This is why the dupe hammer privilege _exists_, is to help stamp out this stuff. Of course it's a losing battle...

Comment: I'm not against marking this question is duplicate. My only argument was that the the predating question should have a meaningful title so it becomes searchable and possibly one should edit it to make it generic—to avoid such wastage.

Comment: @leznevo100: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We will try to help you, but you might it make easier for us: 
1) You should clearly say what’s your problem. Your should provide wherever possible code, not screenshots. So other people could copy and test it. 
2) Your code stops at a breakpoint. The logs say that it can’t find a certain image, when it tries to create to dequeue a cell with identifier „PlayerCell“. Maybe you did set up in Storyboard a tableViewCell that contains an image „Players.png“ that is not contained in you target.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've hit a breakpoint. Breakpoints let you pause and run through your code step by step. You can learn more about the debugger [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/debugging_with_xcode/chapters/debugging_tools.html).

Comment: Actually, this is a comment, and not an answer to the problem

Comment: @ReinhardMänner: It answers the question sufficiently. It is an answer.