# ElementQuiz app- thread 1: breakpoint 1.4

Tags: swift, xcode

I'm trying to build an ElementQuiz app using the book "App Development with Swift" (from iBooks). When I run the app, it crashes and goes to the AppDelegate page, and shows a green line that says "thread 1: breakpoint 1.4".

Here's the ViewController.swift:

```
// ViewController.swift

// ElementQuiz

import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
   override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()
      updateElement()
   }

   @IBOutlet weak var image view: UIImageView!

   @IBOutlet weak var answerLabel: UILabel!

   @IBAction func showAnswer(_sender: Any) {
      answerLabel.text = elementList[currentElementIndex]
   }

   @IBAction func gotoNextElement(_sender: Any) {
      currentElementIndex += 1
      if currentElementIndex >= elementList.count {
         currentElementIndex = 0
      }

      updateElement()
   }

   let elementList = ["Carbon", "Gold", "Chlorine", "Sodium"]

   var currentElementIndex = 0

   func updateElement() {
      answerLabel.text = "?" 

      let elementName = elementList[currentElementIndex]
      let image = UIImage(named: elementName)
      imageView.image = image
   }
}
```

And here's the AppDelegate.swift:

```
//AppDelegate.swift
//ElementQuiz

import UIKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

   // This is the line with the "signal SIGABRT" error.
   var window: UIWindow?

   func application(_application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

      //Override point for customization after application launch.
      return true
   }
}
```

That was my code.

Comment: Most probably a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32038226/error-thread-1-breakpoint-2-1 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10016890/thread-1-stopped-at-breakpoint-error-when-initializing-an-nsurl-object – Simply remove the breakpoint, or choose "continue" from the debugger menu.

Answer (score 0):

Delete all connections here (see the picture). Only you have this connection.

[image: connection event]